# Typescript syntax highlighting in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

How can I get syntax highlighting for typescript (.ts) files in Netbeans?

This sounds like a simple thing but I've searched for this and I cant seem to find the solution.

Comment: There's an open ticket for this issue: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233197

Answer (score 1):

As a stopgap solution, you can use this Netbeans plugin for Typescript
    https://github.com/Everlaw/nbts/releases

You will need NodeJS for it to work. After installing both the plugin and NodeJS, navigate to Tools | Options | HTML/JS and select the NodeJS tab to make the plugin aware of NodeJS.

Import your Typescript files into a new HTML5/JS project.

However, indenting does not work for me using this plugin.